# Playwright (angular) expect fails with empty array when it's not empty

Tags: angular, playwright

I have an Assert checking the array of a dropdown list vs a hard coded Array.  When I set the array to the dropdown allInnerText(), the variable shows a length of 1, and the expected array.  When checking in the expect, it's coming back with an actual of Array[] (empty).  I have a feeling I'm missing something small, but am stuck as to why it's failing.

```
const ddlList = await getDropdownListOptions();  // ddlList = ['Item 1\nItem 2\nItem 3\nItem 4']; when debugging
const expectedList: string[] = ['Item 1\nItem 2\nItem 3\nItem 4'];
console.log(ddlList);
console.log(expectedList);
expect(ddlList).toEqual(expectedList);

async getDropdownListOptions() : Promise<string[]> {
    return await this.page.locator('my locator query here').allInnerTexts();
}
```

When debugging, both ddlList and expectedList appear to be the same.  **proto** = Array(0), length = 1 and the values match.

When the expect statement executes, it fails it gives the following error (Note: it's the same error whether using expect(ddlList).toBe(expectedList) or expect(ddlList).toEqual(expectedList):

[image: Test failed screenshot]

After adding console.log(ddlList) and console.log(expectedList), it further shows they should be equal and pass the expect(ddlList).toEqual(expectedList).  See screenshot below:

[image: console log screenshot]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: try to `console.log(ddList) ` just before the test to see if it is really awaiting for result of `getDropdownListOptions()` or not

Comment: I did a console.log(ddlList) and console.log(expectedList) and both look identical in the debug console.  I'll add a screenshot to OP

Comment: I also replaced the failure output with a screenshot to better show what playwright is showing when it fails

Comment: @AndyGiebel Is the dropdown list a bunch of options from a select element or some other element?  Could you post the element(s) you are locating on please?